# How to remove a item from one object and then add that item to another object of same array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove an item from one object and then add that item to another object of the same array in JavaScript. In the following array, I want to remove **2163** item from **column-1** object. and then add 2163 to **column-2** itemids.

```
[
{
    "id": "column-1",
    "title": "New",
    "itemIds": [
        "2163",
        "3477",
        "9639"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-2",
    "title": "Active",
    "itemIds": [
        "6018",
        "7028",
        "4491"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-3",
    "title": "Resolved",
    "itemIds": [
        "9156"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-4",
    "title": "Closed",
    "itemIds": [
        "3773",
        "6317",
        "6868"
    ]
}
]
```

I tried the following code

```
        let activeitemId = 2163;
        let truncatedvalue= columns[indexOfactiveColumn].itemIds.filter(function(e) { 
        return e !== activeitemId })
   
        let addedvalue =    [...columns[indexOfoverColumn].itemIds,activeitemId];
         const label = 'itemIds';
        const newValue = truncatedvalue;
        const addednewvalue = addedvalue;
        const updatedArray = [
          ...columns.slice(0, indexOfactiveColumn),
        {  
            ...columns[indexOfactiveColumn],
            [label]: newValue,
         
        },
          ...columns.slice(indexOfactiveColumn + 1),
         

        ];

        console.log('columnall-updatedArray',updatedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const columns = [
    {
        "id": "column-1",
        "title": "New",
        "itemIds": [
            "2163",
            "3477",
            "9639"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "column-2",
        "title": "Active",
        "itemIds": [
            "6018",
            "7028",
            "4491"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "column-3",
        "title": "Resolved",
        "itemIds": [
            "9156"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "column-4",
        "title": "Closed",
        "itemIds": [
            "3773",
            "6317",
            "6868"
        ]
    }
];

const itemIdToRemove = "2163";

// Find the index of the item in column-1 and remove it
const col1 = columns.find(col => col.id === "column-1");
const index = col1.itemIds.indexOf(itemIdToRemove);
if (index !== -1) {
    col1.itemIds.splice(index, 1);
}

// Add the item to column-2
const col2 = columns.find(col => col.id === "column-2");
col2.itemIds.push(itemIdToRemove);

console.log(columns);
```

Comment: Nice! can we do this with spread operator? as push not working with react

Comment: Use `append` to add an element to an array in JS

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan something like `col2.itemIds = [...col2.itemIds,itemIdToRemove]` ?

Comment: Not working... only a spread operator is allowed! please help

Comment: I wants to return whole updated column!

Answer (score 0):

Map the column array into an updated one while adding or filtering out the active item id:

```js
const activeitemId = '2163';
const indexOfoverColumn = 1;

const updatedArray = columns.map(({itemIds, ...item}, i) => ({
  ...item, 
  itemIds: i === indexOfoverColumn  ? [...itemIds, activeitemId] : itemIds.filter(id => id !== activeitemId)
}));
  
console.log(updatedArray);
```

```html
<script> const columns = 
[
{
    "id": "column-1",
    "title": "New",
    "itemIds": [
        "2163",
        "3477",
        "9639"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-2",
    "title": "Active",
    "itemIds": [
        "6018",
        "7028",
        "4491"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-3",
    "title": "Resolved",
    "itemIds": [
        "9156"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-4",
    "title": "Closed",
    "itemIds": [
        "3773",
        "6317",
        "6868"
    ]
}
]
</script>
```

If your over column is the same as the active one you can do more safe code and allow to drag items in the same column to the bottom of the items:

```js
const activeitemId = '2163';
const indexOfoverColumn = 1;

const updatedArray = columns.map(({itemIds, ...item}, i) => ({
  ...item, 
  itemIds: itemIds.filter(id => id !== activeitemId).concat(i === indexOfoverColumn ? [activeitemId] : [])
}));
  
console.log(updatedArray);
```

```html
<script> const columns = 
[
{
    "id": "column-1",
    "title": "New",
    "itemIds": [
        "2163",
        "3477",
        "9639"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-2",
    "title": "Active",
    "itemIds": [
        "6018",
        "7028",
        "4491"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-3",
    "title": "Resolved",
    "itemIds": [
        "9156"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "column-4",
    "title": "Closed",
    "itemIds": [
        "3773",
        "6317",
        "6868"
    ]
}
]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that accepts 4 args.

- **targetArray**: the Array object. (string)
- **deleteFromArrayId**: Delete from this Array Id. (string)
- **addToArrayId**: Add to this Array Id. (string)
- **itemString**: item to delete and add (string)

Note: Spread operator used as requested from your comment above.

```js
function moveItemfromAtoB(targetArray, deleteFromArrayId, addToArrayId, itemString) {
  const deleteFromArrayIndex = targetArray.findIndex(column => column.id === deleteFromArrayId);
  const addToArrayIndex = targetArray.findIndex(column => column.id === addToArrayId);

  if (deleteFromArrayIndex !== -1 && addToArrayIndex !== -1) {
    const itemIndex = targetArray[deleteFromArrayIndex].itemIds.findIndex(itemId => itemId === itemString);

    if (itemIndex !== -1) {
      const updatedDeleteFromArray = {
        ...targetArray[deleteFromArrayIndex],
        itemIds: targetArray[deleteFromArrayIndex].itemIds.filter((_, index) => index !== itemIndex)
      };

      const updatedAddToArray = {
        ...targetArray[addToArrayIndex],
        itemIds: [...targetArray[addToArrayIndex].itemIds, itemString]
      };

      const updatedTargetArray = [...targetArray];
      updatedTargetArray[deleteFromArrayIndex] = updatedDeleteFromArray;
      updatedTargetArray[addToArrayIndex] = updatedAddToArray;

      return updatedTargetArray;
    }
  }

  return targetArray;
}

const itemArray = [{
    "id": "column-1",
    "title": "New",
    "itemIds": ["2163", "3477", "9639"]
  },
  {
    "id": "column-2",
    "title": "Active",
    "itemIds": ["6018", "7028", "4491"]
  },
  {
    "id": "column-3",
    "title": "Resolved",
    "itemIds": ["9156"]
  },
  {
    "id": "column-4",
    "title": "Closed",
    "itemIds": ["3773", "6317", "6868"]
  }
];

console.log(moveItemfromAtoB(itemArray, "column-1", "column-2", "2163"))
```